# Como hago para colocar en una condicion que si se repite un elemento de un array n veces me lo sustituya por una palabra en javascript?

Tags: javascript

El ejercicio es sustituir: por cada 0 un boom por cada 1 un drop the base pero si el 1 se repite 3 veces seguidas tiene que salir break the base.

```js
var boom = "Boom";
var brop = "Drop the base";
var breakBase = "¡¡¡Break the base!!!";

function lyricsGenerator(array) {
  newA = [];
  array.forEach(item => {
    if (item == 0) {
      newA.push(boom)
    } else if (item == 1) {
      newA.push(brop)
    } else if (item = 1, 1, 1) {
      newA.push(breakBase) // aqui la condicion de repeticion 
    }
  });
  return newA
}

console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([1, 0, 1]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([1, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: `item` solo contiene un valor. No 3. Te será útil agregar una variable extra que lleve la cuenta de repeticiones.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes sencillamente comparar con las 2 posiciones anteriores:

```js
var boom = "Boom";
var brop = "Drop the base";
var breakBase = "¡¡¡Break the base!!!";

function lyricsGenerator(array) {
  return array.map((item, index) => {
    if(item === 0){ 
      return boom; 
    } else if(item === 1) { 
      if(array[index-1] == 1 && array[index-2] == 1) { //Revisas si las 2 posiciones anteriorer tambien fueron 1
        return breakBase;
      } else {
        return brop;
      }
    }
  });
}

console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([1, 0, 1]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([1, 1, 1]))
```

Nota: Como lo que quieres es devolver un `array`, para eso se puede usar el `map`, lo que permite quitar la declaración del nuevo array y los `push` hacia él.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te han dicho en los comentarios, lo habitual es usar una variable que va contando las veces que sale seguidas.

En mi solución la he llamado **sum1**, pues suma los unos.

```js
var boom = "Boom";
var brop = "Drop the base";
var breakBase = "¡¡¡Break the base!!!";

function lyricsGenerator(array) {
  newA = [];
  let sum1 = 0  
  array.forEach(item => {
    if (item == 0) {
      newA.push(boom)
      sum1 = 0
    } else if (item == 1) {
      sum1++
      if (sum1 == 3) {
        newA.push(breakBase) // aqui la condicion de repeticion 
        sum1 = 0
      } else {
        newA.push(brop)
      }
    }
  });
  return newA
}

console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([0, 0, 0]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([1, 0, 1]))
console.log(lyricsGenerator([1, 1, 1]))
```